# How to get value of variable defined in testplan and from csv file with groovy in jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

[image: I have variable name message defined in test plan. I want it to be a value of data in groovy. After implementing this I am getting error.]

I am trying to pass a variable in groovy in JSR223 sampler. The variable is defined in test plan. Basically there are ${user_id} and ${__time(,curTime)} defined for value of Message in Test Plan **${user_id}** is the value i am getting from csv file and **${__time(,curTime)}** is function for current time in millisecond.
Basically i want a value in output as user_id corresponding with timestamp in millisecond.

For E.g if value of **${user_id}** is abcd and value of  **${__time(,curTime)}** is 1478965236574 then, i am expecting value as **abcd1478965236574** in the variable data in JSR223 sampler. Can i get this value?

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to concatenate 2 variables: `user_id` and `curTime`

   ```
   def value = vars.get("user_id") + vars.get("curTime");
   ```
2. If you want to generate the new timestamp"

   ```
   def value = vars.get("user_id") + System.currentTimeMillis()
   ```

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance which provides read/write access to JMeter Variables in scope.

Remember that you should not inline JMeter Variables and Functions like `${Message}` into the script body, use `vars.get("Message")` instead as inlining variables causes compilation caching failure hence you loose the major Groovy benefit. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for more detailed explanation and scripting best practices.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri That is what I am looking for.
Can i get the output from logs in to HTTP Request of jmeter?

Comment: The answer is above: use `vars.put("encodedData", encodedData)` in Groovy and refer the value as `${encodedData}` where required, in your case in HTTP Request sampler

Comment: Thanks A Lot. I got the solution.